# How can I hide UIBarbuttonItem on UIToolbar for small size class?

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar, size-classes

It's so pity that `UIToolbar` doesn't support size classes for `UIBarbuttonItem` elements. How can I hide `UIBarbuttonItem` on `UIToolbar` for small size class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, add this:

```
- (void)traitCollectionDidChange:(UITraitCollection *)previousTraitCollection {
    [super traitCollectionDidChange:previousTraitCollection];
    if ((self.traitCollection.verticalSizeClass != previousTraitCollection.verticalSizeClass)
        || (self.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass != previousTraitCollection.horizontalSizeClass)) {
        [self setupToolbar:self.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass];
    }
}
```

And then recreate toolbar items:

```
    if (horizontalSizeClass == UIUserInterfaceSizeClassCompact) {
        mainItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:..., nil];
    } else {
        mainItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:..., nil];
    }
    [mainToolbar setItems:mainItems animated:NO];
```